# BizTalk - Binding property -“useAmbientTransaction” = False

Tags: biztalk

In BizTalk application we are configuring a WCF-ORACLEDB send port adapter to call Stored proc. In the portbinding file we have set `useAmbientTransaction” = False` but in the sendport this value in the binding coming as true. This is happening one specific environment. Other environment its coming as false as mentioned in the port binding file.

This happening one specific environment

```
useAmbientTransaction = False
```

Because this value coming as true we are getting some oracle connection error.

Please advise why this value override to true only one specific environment.

Comment: can you share your sendport details? the oracle binding parameters? and the error you are getting in event logs

Comment: Error details-------------A message sent to adapter "WCF-OracleDB" on send port "<send port name>" with URI "<uri>" is suspended. 
 Error details: Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.ConnectionException ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object sr

Comment: Hi bibB, please use the [edit] link under the question to add any new information.

Comment: How are you deploying the binding?  Or are you just deploying the DLLs and the binding is reverting to the wrong setting in that one environment?

Answer (score 0):

I could name numerous things that could be wrong, but for issues like this it's best to start all over again, so:

1. Remove the ports on all the servers you are trying to deploy to.
2. Create the send port again from scratch on your dev machine.
3. Export the bindings.
4. Remove the send port on the dev machine.
5. Test it on your dev machine by importing the bindings.
6. Now test it on the machine where you had issues.

If the issue still persists, try setting the value manually in the Admin console, does the value stay on `True`? (this is the default value i think) Maybe there aren't enough permissions for you to change the value.